# Invoke JUnit test case from multiple threads

Tags: java, junit

I want to test my JUnit test cases from multiple threads to check how my functionality works in multi-threaded env. TestNG has a nice way to do it `@Test(invocationCount = 100, threadPoolSize = 10)`. How can I do similar in JUnit.

Thanks,
NN

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish this with junit, but I would create a unit test using an `ExecutorService` and sending lot of `Runnable` object instances where each one performs the desired method.

Comment: Also, since it looks you want to execute performance and/or stress testing, you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1065197.